# xcodebuild failed to launch '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/otest' via Jenkins

Tags: objective-c, jenkins, xcodebuild

error: failed to launch '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/otest' -- failed to get the task for process 34796

Hi,

When I run the command:
    /usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme my_scheme_name -configuration Debug build test

I get the following error:
error: failed to launch '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/otest' -- failed to get the task for process 34796

This only happens when the command is executed via Jenkins. Doesn't happen when I execute it from command line.

Has anyone else run into something like this?

The build itself builds an objective c library and the tests are SenTestCases.  It's not an iOS app - it's an objective c library to be used in various apps

Answer (score 2):

I used `sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable` to get past this problem.